# Adding a numerical series with altered rules for addition

Tags: python-3.x

I am running into a mental block and am having trouble getting this to work.
The use for this is to add two different codes together index by index.

I need the output to stay the same number of digits.
The output needs to stay as a binary number.
Inputs will be between 4 and 26 digits.

This is what I have so far.

```
# Mutation Code Addition
''' 
1 + 1 will become 0 
1 + 0 will become 1 
0 + 0 will stay 0
'''
Code1 = '100100'
Code2 = '101011'
# Output should be '001111'

for i in range(len(Code1)):
    Code = '000000'
    if (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 2:
        Code[i].replace('0','0')
    elif (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 1:
        Code[i].replace('0','1')
print(Code)
```

Comment: I answered my own question. 
```
l = '123456'
Code1 = '100100'
Code2 = '101011'

for i in range(len(Code1)):
    if (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 2:
        l = l[:i] + '0' + l[i+1:]
    elif (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 1:
        l = l[:i] + '1' + l[i+1:] 
    elif (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 0:
        l = l[:i] + '0' + l[i+1:] 
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to think about it longer, I figured it out.

```
l = '123456'
Code1 = '100100'
Code2 = '101011'

for i in range(len(Code1)):
    if (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 2:
        l = l[:i] + '0' + l[i+1:]
    elif (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 1:
        l = l[:i] + '1' + l[i+1:] 
    elif (int(Code1[i]) + int(Code2[i])) == 0:
        l = l[:i] + '0' + l[i+1:] 
print(l)
```

output = 001111